# Yii bootstrap submit a form inside a modal window using the modal buttons

Tags: forms, yii, modal-dialog, yii-booster

I'm trying to submit a form from inside a modal window using the modal buttons in the modal-footer. 
The form itself is loaded through ajax from a link (controller/action).

Just to be clearer I attached this picture:
[image]

**This is the code for the modal:**

```
<?php $this->beginWidget('bootstrap.widgets.TbModal', array('id'=>'modal')); ?>

<div class="modal-header">
    <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</a>
    <h4>Client Ticket Status Update</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">

</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbButton', array(
        'buttonType'=>'ajaxSubmit',
        'type'=>'primary',
        'label'=>'Save changes',
        'url'=>'#',
        'htmlOptions'=>array('data-dismiss'=>'modal'),
    )); ?>
    <?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbButton', array(
        'label'=>'Close',
        'url'=>'#',
        'htmlOptions'=>array('data-dismiss'=>'modal'),
    )); ?>
</div>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

**This is the javascript that loads the form inside the modal:**

```
$("a[data-toggle=modal]").click(function(){
    var target = $(this).attr('data-target');
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    if(url){
        $(target).find(".modal-body").load(url);
    }
});
```

**This is the form view:**

```
<div class="form">

<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'client-ticket-form',
    'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
)); ?>

    <p class="note">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required. </p>


    <?php echo $form->errorSummary($ticket); ?>

    <div>
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($ticket,'sent_to'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($ticket,'sent_to'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($ticket,'sent_to'); ?>
    </div>

    <div>
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($ticket,'courier'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($ticket,'courier'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($ticket,'courier'); ?>
    </div>

    <div>
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($ticket,'awb'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($ticket,'awb'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($ticket,'awb'); ?>
    </div>

    <div>
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($ticket,'awb_date'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($ticket,'awb_date'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($ticket,'awb_date'); ?>
    </div>


    <div class="buttons">
        <?php echo CHtml::submitButton($ticket->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Save'); ?>
    </div>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>

</div><!-- form -->
```

Any help is very appreciated. If you require more information, please ask.

Comment: what's that game in you taskbar?

Comment: Hi, It's Battlefield 4. ") awesome game by the way.

Comment: It helped me Raven_ 007, thanks. U gave me an idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change code at model-footer as below:

```
<div class="modal-footer">
<?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbButton', array(
    'type'=>'primary',
    'label'=>'Save changes',
    'url'=>'#',
    'htmlOptions'=>array('onclick' => '$("#formID").submit()'),
)); ?>
<?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbButton', array(
    'label'=>'Close',
    'url'=>'#',
    'htmlOptions'=>array('data-dismiss'=>'modal'),
)); ?>
```

Comment: It worked perfectly. In my case I used a class name to submit the form, since I want to use a single modal to display and submit multiple forms. You're awesome, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This first response didn't resolve my problem of a modal form closing on submit. For anyone else that is having issues, I had to enable client Validation in the CActiveForm.

It ended up looking like this:

```
$form = $this->beginWidget(
    'CActiveForm',
     array(
         'id' => 'feature-form',
         'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
         'enableClientValidation' => true,
         'clientOptions' => array(
             'validateOnSubmit' => true,
             'validateOnChange' => true,
             'validateOnType' => true
          )
        )
);
```

Hopefully this helps some coming after me.

Answer (score 0):

just trigger the click event on the other one that you don't want to show, an also hide it first!